# htaccess folder to domain rewriterule not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this code in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^ext(.*)$ https://newweb.site/parent/ext/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^assets(.*)$ https://newweb.site/parent/assets$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^styles(.*)$ https://newweb.site/parent/styles$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^images(.*)$ https://newweb.site/parent/images$1 [R,L]

# The following 3 lines will rewrite URLs passed through the front controller to not require app.php in the actual URL. In other words, a controller is by default accessed at /app.php/my/controller, but can also be accessed at /my/controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

(The last one refers to phpBB)
Given that I do not know how .htaccess works, I tried this code to redirect all the elements of four different folders to an external domain.
In practice it should come like this:

```
oldwebsite.net/ext/file.js --> newwebsite.com/parentdir/ext/file.js
oldwebsite.net/assets/file.css --> newwebsite.com/parentdir/assets/file.css
oldwebsite.net/images/file.png --> newwebsite.com/parentdir/assets/file.png
...
```

the problem of these four rules is that only the first line does't works, but it's the same of the others..

Can you tell me a more effective and effective way to handle my problem?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since you know that the redirected paths are `<PATH>/someting.js`, you should put the `/` in there.  Ex `RewriteRule ^ext/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/parent/ext/something.js`.  This will prevent a problem if you call `extension/tata`, where `extension` is != `/ext/`

Comment: Nothing changes...

Comment: Remove that first line (the /ext one) and try again.  What happens?  Is the "new" first line not work now?